# How to add ID in API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I am working on Angular Project. I have to add record ID in API. I can get the ID in console but i couldn't add that in an API.
 This is my API **http://localhost:3000/api/abc/getbyID/5bfbed353ccff8326c772eee**.This works well in **POSTMAN**

**abc.service.ts**

```
  getABCByID(abc,token): Observable<any> {
    console.log(abc); // I can get id in console
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBase+'/api/abc/getbyID/${abc}',{
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    });
  };
```

**Issue:** ${abc} is not getting the ID here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enclose with ` not  '

```
`/api/abc/getbyID/${abc}`
```

read more her on **[String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are trying to concat id with api using string literals. so replace `'` with `.

just replace it with your code.

```
getABCByID(abc,token): Observable<any> {
    console.log(abc); // I can get id in console
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBase+`/api/abc/getbyID/${abc}`,{
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `concat` string here as in javascript like this -

```
const url = environment.apiBase + '/api/abc/getbyID/' + abc;
```

so your code should be -

```
getABCByID(abc,token): Observable<any> {
    console.log(abc); // I can get id in console
    const url = environment.apiBase + '/api/abc/getbyID/' + abc;
    return this.http.get(url,{
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    });
  };
```

Or in case you want to use string literals you need to use enclose string in **backticks** not in **quotes**.